# Is File namespace durable?

Tags: c#

I always interested how this function (for example) works:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

In three situtations:

1. Thread abortation
2. Process kill
3. Power shutdown

Will file write be durable in these three situtations? Will file be corrupted/partially written?

**PS** Im also interested in other functions from this namespace, but this will be too broad for SO question.

Comment: Just see source code http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,943

Comment: Short answer no it isn't, which is why Transactional NTFS was introduced. If you want to avoid corruption write to a temporary file and then replace the existing file with the temporary one with `File.Replace`

Comment: You'll have to be more careful what you mean by "durable". For obvious reasons, no piece of software can guarantee a write will successfully complete if you yank the power plug -- that needs hardware support. Database systems guarantee durability by cooperating with the hardware to ensure that they do not report back a write as fully successful until the hardware tells them so, and they will undo any partial or corrupted writes on startup where they did not get this guarantee.

Comment: Even if you have completed the write and then yank the plug write caching can be involved and its not on disk yet

Answer (score 4):

> Will file write be durable in these three situations?

Not necessarily, no.

The exact result will depend on so many factors that the only conclusive I can say about this is that it the outcome is undefined.

> Will file be corrupted/partially written?

Possibly. No guarantees one way or the other.

---

So to answer a related question:

Under normal circumstances

- should I ever forcibly abort/kill/terminate a thread? **No!**
- should I ever forcibly abort/kill/terminate a process? **No!**
- should I ever forcibly turn off the computer? **No!**

> So then how do I terminate a thread or a process?

**A:** You ask nicely. You build the thread or process in such a way that external code can *ask* it to terminate. For threads, you will usually do this with boolean flag variables, CancellationTokens for tasks, synchronization objects, etc.

For processes, you can use windows messages or other means, even cross-process synchronization objects.

For turning off power: Use the power button. **Once!**

Comment: Thank you. Thats cleared up some questions in my mind. Also, for another part of your answer, I totally agree with what you have said about interruption of process/threads BUT it doesn't count when you execute uncontrollable/bugged code. So it is main reason these were introduced in a first place. To just kill the problem when it is appearing rather then fixing bug causing uncontrollable execution (mostly you don't even have means to fix it).